# robot with django not working in setting up with module not found

Tags: django, robotframework

I am trying to set up robot framework on django application. I am testing on a skeleton applciation. Following these instructions https://github.com/kitconcept/robotframework-djangolibrary i get error

```
% robot tests/test.robot
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/Users/user/hci/pipeline/app/tests/test.robot' on line 13: Importing library 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/bin
  /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python37.zip
  /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7
  /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
  /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages
==============================================================================
Test :: Django Robot Tests
==============================================================================
Scenario: As a visitor I can visit the django default page            | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
No keyword with name 'Start Django' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test :: Django Robot Tests                                            | FAIL |
Suite setup failed:
No keyword with name 'Start Django' found.

Also suite teardown failed:
No keyword with name 'Stop Django' found.

1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /Users/user/hci/pipeline/app/output.xml
Log:     /Users/user/hci/pipeline/app/log.html
Report:  /Users/user/hci/pipeline/app/report.html
```

This is the content of my files

In `settings.py` I have

```
    """
Django settings for pipeline project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-pn)5i&@5u$yix_%r9&t$=ww=3t8ttaxt=qymg@u^4-q#((u_v#'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'demo',
    'django_jenkins',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'DjangoLibrary.middleware.AutologinAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'DjangoLibrary.middleware.FactoryBoyMiddleware',
    'DjangoLibrary.middleware.QuerySetMiddleware',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'DjangoLibrary.middleware.AutologinAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'DjangoLibrary.middleware.FactoryBoyMiddleware',
    'DjangoLibrary.middleware.QuerySetMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pipeline.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pipeline.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

In `test.robot` i have

```
*** Variables ***

${HOSTNAME}             127.0.0.1
${PORT}                 55001
${SERVER}               http://${HOSTNAME}:${PORT}/
${BROWSER}              firefox


*** Settings ***

Documentation   Django Robot Tests
Library         Selenium2Library  timeout=10  implicit_wait=0
Library         MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES  ${HOSTNAME}  ${PORT}  path=pipeline/pipeline  manage=pipeline/manage.py  settings=pipeline.settings
Suite Setup     Start Django and open Browser
Suite Teardown  Stop Django and close Browser


*** Keywords ***

Start Django and open Browser
  Start Django
  Open Browser  ${SERVER}  ${BROWSER}

Stop Django and close browser
  Close Browser
  Stop Django


*** Test Cases ***

Scenario: As a visitor I can visit the django default page
  Go To  ${SERVER}
  Wait until page contains element  id=explanation
  Page Should Contain  It worked!
  Page Should Contain  Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.
```

I am using python3.7.2

UPDATE

I have updated it but now i get this error

```
% robot tests/test.robot
==============================================================================
Test :: Django Robot Tests
==============================================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/hci/pipeline/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/user/hci/pipeline/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 230, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 261, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 380, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
No changes detected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/hci/pipeline/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/user/hci/pipeline/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 230, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 261, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 380, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/hci/pipeline/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/user/hci/pipeline/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 230, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 261, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 380, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Django started (PID: 51422)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scenario: As a visitor I can visit the django default page            | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Django stopped (PID: 51422)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test :: Django Robot Tests                                            | FAIL |
Suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.


1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /Users/user/hci/pipeline/app/output.xml
Log:     /Users/user/hci/pipeline/app/log.html
Report:  /Users/user/hci/pipeline/app/report.html
```

Comment: The error says no keyword named "Start Django" was found, and in the source you provide there really isn't such - thus RF doesn't have anything to run; the same for the Stop Django in the teardown. Is it in that library you import?

Comment: where do I import it?

Comment: I'm talking about this import statement, `Library         MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, does the "Start Django" come from it? If not - where is it defined, and made visible to the suite?

Comment: I added my settings.py file. i don't understand how you import it

Comment: Do you have a file named `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.py` in your PATH?